# Why do some images load from the bottom?

Tags: images, rendering

Why do some images render from the bottom? I have seen them in the past but I have never thought of it much. Today I was browsing this page of [ZeusEdit](http://www.zeusedit.com/lookmain.html) editor and middle-clicked on one of the screenshots and noticed that the image loaded from the bottom. I am asking since I searched here and did not find any similar questions.

*Middle-clicking opens an image in the new tab.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in the image file, they are stored from the bottom up, like Microsoft's BMP format.

Comment: +1: That way they are read to the video card quicker.